# For loop not finding all words in string array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to add Countries to an Excel Document with some information on adoption. The information is online at [HERE](http://www.rainbowkids.com/Countries/CountryGuideLines.aspx?id=64). I've been working this backwards so I can at least have something to show in the next couple hours. I've added what I really want to do at the bottom of this question in case you are curious.

I have found the problem to be with the carriage returns and newlines. I'm working on fixing that then I'll upload the solution.

I'm passing a string with about 450 words in it. I have 2 '>>>' and 2 '<<' in it. My output is only showing me that it only found 1 '>>>'. Is there something I'm missing? I'm about to start pulling my hair out.

```
private void FindCountries(string text) {
        text = text.Replace("\n", " "); //This 3 lines fixed the problem. 
        text = text.Replace("\r", " "); //Without these and string in the array was 
        text = text.Replace("\t", " "); //looking like this: "<<\r\n\r>>>" 
        string[] helper = text.Split(' ');
        //List<string> myContries = new List<string>();
        List<int> j = new List<int>();
        List<int> k = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < helper.Length; i++) {
            if (helper[i] == ">>>") {
            Console.WriteLine(helper[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("added to j");
                j.Add(i);
            }
            if (helper[i] == "<<") {
                Console.WriteLine("added to k");
                k.Add(i);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("J");
        foreach (var item in j) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("K");
        foreach (var item in k) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

Project description:
Go to a website.
Grab all the information.(Right now I'm here working my way up.)
Put it in an Excel Doc nicely.

Comment: You could try debugging it.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yeah give me a minute.

Comment: @Mephy Thanks. That has pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test with an input string of `"foo << bar >>> baz >>> qux << quxx >>>"` worked as expected.

Without knowing what the input is, I can only guess, but 1 possibility is that one of the occurrences of `>>>` is not delimited by a space on both sides, meaning it won't appear by itself when you split the input.

Comment: Yes this works. I found the problem to be with \r and \n. Do you know how to get rid of those?

Comment: This worked as well. How do I go about giving credit for this question?

Comment: @Mike there should be a checkmark next to each answer - you can click the one next to the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void FindCountries(string text)
{
var words = text.Split(' ');
//List<string> myContries = new List<string>();
var tripleRights = new List<int>();
var doubleLefts = new List<int>();

for (var index = 0; index < words.Length; index++)
{
    if (String.Equals(words[index], ">>>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {

        Console.WriteLine(words[index]);
        Console.WriteLine("found a triple right");
        tripleRights.Add(index);
    }

    if (String.Equals(words[index], "<<", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {

        Console.WriteLine(words[index]);
        Console.WriteLine("found a double left");
        doubleLefts.Add(index);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("triple rights:");
foreach (var item in tripleRights)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
Console.WriteLine("double lefts");
foreach (var item in doubleLefts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do something like:

```
string test = "23 <<< hello <<< to >> here <<<";

int found=0;
int seek_pos =0;

while (true) {
    var current = test.IndexOf("<<<", seek_pos);
    if (current == -1) 
        break;  
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("found one at position {0}, starting at: {1} ", current, seek_pos);
        found++;
        seek_pos = current + 3 ; // 3 chars in <<<
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Total found: {0} ",found);
```

Giving as results:

```
found one at position 3, starting at: 0 
found one at position 13, starting at: 6 
found one at position 28, starting at: 16 
Total found: 3
```